# Analyzing summary Report in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, statistics, summary

Hi stack Overflow community,

as a new bie in Jmeter,I hope u will bear my question

I developed script in Jmeter using blazemeter..all fine.

i execute this for 1,15,50 Users(in Non Gui Mode ,not including any Listners).All well
when i analysis summary reports i found smthing suspicious (1 sample http request)

blue for 1 user,green for 15 and  yellow for 15 Users
i m not able to explain customer why Received KB/sec and Sent KB/sec doesn't give

a pattern with increase no of user
[image: summary Report]

```
 Sent KB/sec (1User)<Sent KB/sec (15User) but
 Sent KB/sec (50User)<Sent KB/sec (1User)  same as received KB/sec
  i.e.
   Sent KB/sec (50User)<Sent KB/sec (1User)<Sent KB/sec (15User)
   Received KB/sec (50User)<Received KB/sec (1User)<Received KB/sec 
  (15User)
```

How its possible.
what i m missing
Note:I m using Ramp Up time

Thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Average response time for 50 users (200 seconds), the reason for the decrease of Throughput is that the requests hold in the server queue for a long time, and therefore there was not to much data exchange between server and client.

You can generate [Dashboard Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#generation) by yourself or [in the cloud](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/09/generating-jmeter-report-dashboard/) as well, and get more information and analytics by running JMeter in Non-GUI mode:

```
jmeter -n -t <path_to.jmx> -l <log.jtl> -e -o <dashboard_folder>
```